# How to bind events in mootools after ajax response

Tags: ajax, mootools, mootools-events

Any idea how to bind `mouseover` events in mootools after an ajax response.

Tried as follows

```
onSuccess : function(responseTree, responseElements, responseHTML, responseJavaScript) {

              Elements.from(responseHTML).inject($('load-content'));

            $('load-content').fireEvent('mouseover');

            }
```

but it won't works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
$('load-content').addEvent('mouseover', function(e){
    // your code
});
```